# Detemining whether a particle is stable with respect to the electromagnetic, EM or strong force

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model

If we have some beautiful hadron , how can we decide based on the quantum numbers and masses of the other beautiful hadrons whether it is stable under the electromagnetic, weak or strong interaction .

Here is some things I think might be relevant information :

1)All hadrons with approximately the same mass transform under the same representation in the SU(3) group.

2)hadrons with the same quantum number fall into a multiplet of that quantum number.

3)$b$ quarks always are produced in quark antiquark pairs $b\bar{b}$ which can then separate into different particles which do not decay by strong interactions but only by weak interactions.

My Guess at what I think might be the right path :

From what I said above in 3) I think it would mean that any particle containing a $b$ quark must be stable under strong and EM interactions but decay under weak interactions.

As for how to decide this based solely off looking at the masses and quantum numbers of other beautiful hadrons rather than just assuming it axiomatically , I'm utterly lost, could anyone point me in the right direction with some theory please ?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with looking at multiplets , but I'm not sure